# YouTube Embedded video views aren't counted in android app

Tags: android, webview, youtube-iframe-api

I (actually my app team) embed my YouTube videos on the app.
The videos are played well in the app, but video views aren't counted.
We use YouTube IFrame API and android webview.
We checked the views are counted in PC and mobile, so we think IFrame API is okay.
We think the view-count problem is from Android webview. 
Doesn't Android webview count YouTube video views originally?
I don't set autoplay for video watching.
Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you could ask someone of you "app team" to post a question, providing what is currently the situation is

Comment: Hi Nebulosar, That was they told me. Their English isn't okay, so I am seeking a solution here. Thank you for your tip!

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable autoplay and let users play the video through the native play button since: "YouTube only counts playbacks that are initiated through the native play button." [REF](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer)